# fading in my image gallery

Tags: jquery

I have an image gallery and I want to add fade effect, How can I do do this in this code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".gallery div").mouseover(function(){
    $(".gallery div").removeClass("current");
    $(this).toggleClass("current");
});
 });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".gallery div").hover(function(){
    $(".gallery div").removeClass("current").fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).toggleClass("current").fadeIn('fast');
});
 });
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".gallery div").mouseover(function(){
  $(".gallery div").removeClass("current");
  $(".gImg").fadeTo("slow", 0.33)
  $(this).toggleClass("current");
  

 });
}); 
 
this code, fade the .gImg image but " $(".gImg").stop().fadeTo(200);" cant stop fadeIn

Answer (score 2):

Use the fade [effect](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects).

You can do fadeIn, fadeOut or fadeTo depending on what you need :

```
$("p:first").click(function () {
  $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, fades out on mouseout, fades in on hover?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gallery div").mouseover(function(){
    $(".gallery div").removeClass("current").fadeTo(500, 0.25);
    $(this).toggleClass("current").stop().fadeIn(200);
  });
});
```

You can also do this via the [hover() function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gallery div").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("current").stop().fadeIn(200);
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("current").fadeTo(500, 0.25);
  });
});
```

Comment: @jasmine: What result are you seeing? If you can describe it maybe I can help

Comment: Thank you very much,
Your code fading but not stop the fading in transition